# Using ImportXML to pull URL and anchor

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My goal is to scrape a link containing either a word "apple" or a word "pear", and for each scraped link I need to scrape the anchor.

At present I am using the following:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//a/@href[contains(., 'apple')]")
```

Unfortunately, I can only scrape the links containing apple. Still need to add another condition - "pear" and scrape the anchor.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//a/@href[contains(., 'apple') or contains(., 'pear')]")
```